# Graphics glitches - red and purple flickering pixels

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.10

I have a computer with an RTX 2080 Ti, which I recently updated from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Recently, I've started having screen / graphics issues.

[image: these]

I get random flickering dots all the time (both in games and on the normal Ubuntu workspace, and in games specifically (not on the normal workspace), I get [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQqZdiDjFws) graphics glitches as well.

- The glitches happen on all three of my screens, so it can't be a bad monitor or HDMI cable (which was a potential solution I found on the internet)
- I tried connecting my screens directly to the mainboard, but the glitches still appear
- I am currently using the `nvidia-driver-435` driver, but testing the `-430` or `-440` drivers had the same effect
- When in UEFI, the glitches don't appear
- When I move my mouse over the flickering dots, the cursor is rendered above the flickering dots (i. e. it covers the flickering dot)

I don't think it's the monitors or the cables as it happens with three screens at the same time. I don't think it's the graphics card as it happens when I connect the monitors to the mainboard as well. It has to be some driver or configuration issue. But I tested multiple versions of the driver as well.

What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Nvidia as a primary graphic card not intel (to check it: `prime-select query`)?

Comment: Yeah, `prime-select query` returns `nvidia`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the graphics card in another computer where it had the same issues, and then had it replaced by the store I bought it at. The new card doesn't have this issue, so it looks like this was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Unity Desktop Environment or other DE. Why my answer was deleted? I had similar problems after upgrading 19.04 to 19.10 on GTX 1060 - graphical glitches on Ubuntu/Gnome with opengl rendered windows (sometimes whole Gnome was unreponsive), but I haven't seen it in Unity.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was deleted. It may have appeared not intended to answer the specific question asked here. Or it may have been seen as very low quality (though typically such an answer would garner some downvotes first). I wouldn't have voted to delete it but I don't view it as unreasonable that some people did. *This* answer is more detailed, citing your personal experience and clarifying how it applies to the question here. Your other answer could be undeleted after editing, but since you've also posted a new one I think the best course is to keep this one and not undelete the first one.